# Using the read_excel function in panda to go through all the columns in an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

What the code does below is read a column (named "First") and look for the string "TOM".

I want to go through all the columns in the file ( not just the "First" column) - i was thinking of doing something like excelFile[i][j] where i and j are set in a loop but that does not work. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import re

excelFile=pd.read_excel("test.xls")

for i in excelFile.index:
match=re.match(".*TOM.*",excelFile['First'][i])
if match:
    print(excelFile['First'][i])
    print("check")
```

Comment: You want to find the row and column indices where `"TOM"` is contained somewhere within the string in any cell?

Comment: Yes - something to indicate that “TOM” exists anywhere in the file. I’m basically Just trying to get an idea on how to parse through all the rows and columns in excel sheet so that I can either find values or modify some values based on the regular expression condition.

Comment: the `pandas` string methods tend to be on the slower side if you have a large amount of data. Otherwise you can use `.applymap` to make your code rather concise, for instance `df.applymap(lambda x: 'TOM' in x)` will provide a `Boolean` mask of your entire `DataFrame` that you can combine with `DataFrame.where` to manipulate only those cells.

Comment: thats a good suggestion - let me look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`excelFile.any(axis=None)` will return a boolean value telling you if the value was found anywhere in the dataframe.

[Documentation for pd.DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

To print if the value was found, get the columns from the dataframe and use iterrows:

```
# Create a list of columns in the dataframe
columns = excelFile.columns.tolist()

# Loop through indices and rows in the dataframe using iterrows
for index, row in excelFile.iterrows():
    # Loop through columns
    for col in columns:
        cell = row[col]
        # If we find it, print it out
        if re.match(".*TOM.*", cell):
            print(f'Found at Index: {index} Column: {col}')
```

Comment: worked well - thanks. Just one question - how does the following statement work? i see that we have two variables in the for loop ( index and row ) - are they both getting incremented? "for index, row in excelFile.iterrows():"

Comment: Yes, exactly. They are both being incremented. [pd.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) is a generator which yields both index and row.

Comment: also for the line "cell = row[col]" the value within the square brackets should be an integer right? does this mean that even though "columns" is a list of all the columns ...."col" is just the integer value? I tried doing "cell=col[row]" and that does not work.

Comment: No. Column in the name of the column.

Answer (score 1):

something like this loops through all of the columns and looking for a string match

```
for column in excelFile:
      if 'tom' in column.lower():
          print(column)
```

Comment: what is df defined as?